# Is this a relative pronoun or conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses

> I want to know everything (that) there is to know about you.

I chanced to come across ‘expletive there’ in a syntactic textbook. It says in this type of sentences: *there* is an expletive, *to know about you* is the argument for the verb. Then [there is to know about you] is a complete sentence and there is no grammatical place for ‘(that).’
Then, ‘*(that) there is to know about you* ‘ is not a relative clause but complement for the noun *everything* (adjective clause), and so ‘(that)’ is not a relative pronoun but a conjunction, I think. Can this be a possible and appropriate thought?

Comment: No, it's a relative clause. _Everything_ is an indefinite quantifier and can't really take a complement clause; that's reserved for picture nouns like _rumor_ (_the rumor that Bill and Susie eloped_). However, this is far from the only issue; this sentence has been done an awful lot of things to. _There_-insertion, indefinite subject deletion (subject of _to know_), relative quantifiers, wow. It's pretty close to an idiom.

Comment: Where John Lawler fears to tread I'm not going to venture! That's actually a relief; it's a very complex construction. I'll just say that *that* here can be replaced with *which*, so it **must** be a relative pronoun, not a conjunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be a possible [thought](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/).  Everything that @John Lawler has explained is correct.  There are a lot of things going on in these phrases.

You have noticed (that) "that" as a relative pronoun may be elided in English without necessarily being ungrammatically correct.

However, "there is to know about you" is **not** a complete sentence in that it is not an atomic type.  Not to be reductive, but it is not an independent clause because it begins with the relative pronoun "that," which would not be diagrammed as an SP.

That "that" is not a conjunction. An easy way to remember the most common coordinating conjunctions is the mnemonic "*FANBOYS*," for

- For
- And
- Nor
- But
- Or
- Yet
- So

If it's not on that list, you might be looking at something other than a conjunction.

I hope this helps.  What textbook are you using for your studies?